# Add jetty servlet into dropwizard

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, dropwizard

I need to add jetty servlet into my already existing server implemented using dropwizard framework.

To be more specific:

1. I have a restful resource Foo mapped to url "localhost:8080/foo" with CRUD operations.
2. Now I need a jetty servlet mapped to url "localhost:8080/bar" and handles all requests to this url (mainly GET and POST).

I could not get a clue how to do this after some googlings. Could someone please give me a direction or a snippet? Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you are not able to change the already existing application and you want to add one more application in the same server. If that is the case, cant you use some front end server which re-routes the requests to different applications running on different ports?

Comment: Actually I have the code and I can change it. But rather than change it 'a lot', I want to just implement a servlet and add it in main function.

Comment: I think i am not getting your question clearly. Do you want to route all the requests to /bar into /foo ? or are those two endpoints doing entirely different jobs and you just want to deploy it on single server.

Comment: The latter one. The existing server will still handle requests to '/foo', and the new servlet will handle those on '/bar'. To be convenient in deloyment, I wish to make them run in the same process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using Dropwizard 0.6.2 you should be able to do something like this in your `run` method:

```java
ServletBuilder builder = environment.addServlet(myServlet, "/bar");
```

If you're using Dropwizard 0.7.0 try this:

```java
environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet("org.example.MyServlet", "/bar");
```

Comment: In case someone may care: the second param can contain wildcard character like '/bar/*', otherwise the servlet will only handle requests on '/bar' but not those on '/bar/foo'.

Comment: The 0.7.x API also allows Class<? extends Servlet> as a parameter, you do not have to provide the FQN-String.

Comment: This seems to be the same for Dropwizard 0.8.1

Answer (score 4):

For 0.7.0 you have the [`ServletEnvironment`](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.0/dropwizard-jetty/apidocs/io/dropwizard/jetty/setup/ServletEnvironment.html) and a couple of ways to add servlets. For example:

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.servlets().addServlet("foo", MySerlvet.class).addMapping("/bar");
}
```

Incidentally, you also have the [`AdminEnvironment`](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.0/dropwizard-core/apidocs/io/dropwizard/setup/AdminEnvironment.html), which is an extension of `ServletEnvironment` and any servlets added to this in the same way would accessible on **/admin**/bar.