# Customize Dropwizard's /ping

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

Dropwizard provides a /ping endpoint on it's admin port (7001) that responds with a "pong" string.

Is it possible to customize the behavior of this call? What I'm looking for is to be able to control the response of the call based on application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not Dropwizard that provides this - it's the [metrics library](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/efa52f349d058e660a24097676fc27783ac1d083/metrics-servlets/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/servlets/PingServlet.java).

You could register your own servlet. Or maybe it makes sense to use a [health check](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#health-checks)?

Comment: That's interesting. When you say register your own servlet, is there a public  api to do this from my app code? or you mean forking the library, add my code, and using my custom fork instead?

Comment: You could write your own servlet based on the ping servlet and then register it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239218/add-jetty-servlet-into-dropwizard